# RSelenium findElement function

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I just started learning parsing and am having problems with it ...
I need to scrape this value [from here](https://www.valutrades.com/en/sentiment), but I don't know what I should write in the `findElement` function
[image]

here is my code

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome",port=0999L, 
               verbose=F,chromever = "95.0.4638.54")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.valutrades.com/en/sentiment")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "......", value = "......")
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want to scrape is in `iframe`.

[image]

One way to do is,

```
remDr$navigate('https://csi2.valutrades.com/sentimentgraph.php')
webElem <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="EURUSD"]')
webElem$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "EURUSDLongShort44.3%55.7%"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything worked! Can you explain how you understood that this is an "iframe" and how you got the link to it

Comment: Edited the post. You can see the `iframe` element and the link beside it. You can also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290620/click-on-cross-domain-iframe-element-using-rselenium on other ways to deal with `iframe`.