# Scrape Default Value from Text Input Box in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am able to scrape the table on this Website:-

> https://dailyfantasynerd.com/optimizer/draftkings/nba

using `RSelenium` package.

[image]

The issue is that the Circled Column above is returned as Blank:-

[image]

Now, this Column is editable but I only need to scrape its Default Value (for example 50.7 in the first row).

I am using the following code:-

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"), port = 0001L)

remDr <- driver[["client"]]

url <- 'https://dailyfantasynerd.com/optimizer/draftkings/nba'
remDr$navigate(url)

username <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "input-username")
username$sendKeysToElement(list("xx"))

#send password and Enter
passwd <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "input-password")
passwd$sendKeysToElement(list("xx", "\uE007"))


#get all the tables from webapage 
df = (remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_table())[[7]]
```

Comment: The column you are referring needs subscription plan. The table is located inside `iframe` maybe refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290620/click-on-cross-domain-iframe-element-using-rselenium

Comment: I see. I do have subscription to this website. I can share with you the credentials. Would we able to scrape this data after we have logged in ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct html node? It might be that the `Proj` ,`FP` column are stored in a different node.